# Связать картинки с checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на чекбокс поменялась картинка слева:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Написать код, наверное.

Comment: Ну или скрывайте текущую/показывайте нужную или img src подменяйте

Comment: На чекбокс? Не на радиобаттон, а на чекбокс? Как именно ты это представляешь?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну может там мульён картинок на все варианты и должна происходить подмена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function k() {
document.getElementById('glavnay').src=(document.getElementById('yslygi').checked)? 
   'img/1.jpg': 'img/krovat.JPG'

}

<img src="img/krovat.JPG" id="glavnay">
<input name="Краска" type="checkbox" onclick="k()" id="yslygi" />
```

> Так у меня получилось

Answer (score 0):

Используя JQuery.

```
$(".checkbox1").click(function(){
    $('.some-image-container').html("<img src='new_image.png'>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерный алгоритм таков:

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');    

if (checkbox.checked) {
    replaceImg();
} else {
    setDefaultImg(); 
}
```

Если я правильно понял, то в зависимости от выбранного checkbox`а будет ставиться определенная картинка. В таком случае, я бы передавал в функцию изображение

```
replaceImg(img)
```

Comment: Спасибо за идеи,буду пробовать!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы допустим сделал так. Есть чекбоксы и для каждого прописал бы ссылку так:

```
<input id="checkBox1" type="checkbox" data-img="тут ссылка">
<input id="checkBox2" type="checkbox" data-img="тут ссылка">
<input id="checkBox3" type="checkbox" data-img="тут ссылка">
<input id="checkBox4" type="checkbox" data-img="тут ссылка">
<input id="checkBox5" type="checkbox" data-img="тут ссылка">
<input id="checkBox6" type="checkbox" data-img="тут ссылка">
```

Ну и уже при выборе смотрим на ссылку и заменяем. Например на jquery:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      $(".img").attr('src', $(this).data("img"));
    }
});
```